# Why should we use XMPP instead of JSON for simple (text only) messaging app?

Tags: android, json, node.js, xmpp, instant-messaging

I am creating a simple Android chat app with groups, chat history etc., but "text only".

I have backend developer in Node.js. Googling we found out that XMPP (XML) is the protocol for large scale chats, but for small to medium chat apps (mobile), I believe we can go ahead with JSON and Node.js server.

Want to know if there is any significant advantage on using XMPP?

Answer (score 2):

It is not about simple text message. 
When you want to implement real time chat application you have to notify the all the user of chat window when their is a new message post in thread.

The one way to notify other user is through push notification which is generally not that much reliable. So we use XMPP protocol for that.
Find more details about XMPP [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).

If you don't want to use XMPP protocol then you can achieve the same using socket. And in android their is [socket.io](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) is available which is also a good library for real-time chat.

Comment: do you recommend MQTT over XMPP for the same?

Comment: I don't know about MQTT much and never tested by myself but on socket.io and XMPP I have worked. Both are good and responsive.It's your choice what you prefer to use.

Comment: notifying all uses is also possible with json, can explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

If implementing XMPP, your users may use [XMPP clients](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) of their preference to chat on your server. This way you also reach users on platforms other than Android.